# How to display database table records using TableLayout

Tags: android

I followed the "[How to get data from database in my android table view as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987212/how-to-get-data-from-database-in-my-android-table-view-as-columns/20114467#20114467)" link to resolve my problem
but a blank screen appears without data. On clicking the button I have written code to fetch the records from MS SQL DB.

My XML, for layout purpose, activity_display_result.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab" >
</TableLayout>
```

And the code snippet from *MainActivity.java*:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    }

    initilize();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            List <Map<String,String>> dataList  = querySQL(e1.getText().toString(),e2.getText().toString(),e.getText().toString());

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0;i<dataList.size();i++)
            {               
               Log.i("onClick Method()", "UserName : "+dataList.get(i).get("UserName"));
               Log.i("onClick Method()", "Password : "+dataList.get(i).get("Password"));
               builder.append(dataList.get(i).get("UserName")).append(";").
               append(dataList.get(i).get("Password")).append("_");
            }

            builder.toString();

            String st = new String(builder);
            String[] rows =st.split("_");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_result);
            TableLayout tableLayout =(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
            tableLayout.removeAllViews();

            for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
                String row  = rows[i];
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                                                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                final String[] cols = row.split(";");

                Log.i("MainActivity ","Column length :"+cols.length);

                //Handler handler = null;

                for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
                {             
                    final String col = cols[j];                                 
                    TextView TextView11 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    TextView11.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    TextView11.setTextColor(color.black);
                    //TextView11.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
                    TextView11.setText(col);
                    tableRow.addView(TextView11);
                }

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Declaring all

```
public void declere()
{
    e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

//initializing 
public void initilize()
{
    Log.i("initilize() Method", "initilize() Method is called..Now Calling declere() method");
    declere();
    Log.i("initilize() Method", "declere() method is called ");
    Log.i("initilize() Method", "Before Calling CONN() method..");
    connect=CONN("sa","C!@C2@!2","RequestCenter");
    Log.i("initilize() Method", "CONN() method called Successfully..");

 }
```

I also added one CONN method for getting connection. Can anyone help me to determine why the screen appears blank ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_result)` at the end of your onClick method, which will reset the view to the content of the xml, hence giving you a blank screen as defined in activity_display_result.xml. You need to remove that line and see if it works.

Comment: i delete that line but still no result on that new window

Answer (score 0):

A couple of  things:

1. You continue to reset the setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_result); many times (via the loop). Is there a a reason? You probably only have to set it once at the end once all your controls have been placed in the layout. I've moved it to where I think it should be in the code below. If that doesn't work, reconsider taking it out as mentioned above by 2Dee
2. A question for my own understanding: Why is `col` set to Final? Would that not prevent the variable from being assigned the next value in the cols array? Thanks!

   ```
       for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
           String row  = rows[i];
           TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                                           tableRow.setLayoutParams(new     TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

           final String[] cols = row.split(";");

           Log.i("MainActivity ","Column length :"+cols.length);

           //Handler handler = null;

           for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
           {             
               final String col = cols[j];                                 
               TextView TextView11 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
               TextView11.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               TextView11.setTextColor(color.black);
               //TextView11.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
               TextView11.setText(col);
               tableRow.addView(TextView11);

           }

          tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
       }
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_result);
   ```